# minimize $L(i, n)$ for a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: optimization

Given some fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I want to minimize the following function of $i$:

$$L(i, n) = \Bigl\lceil \frac{n}{i} \Bigr\rceil + i$$

within limits $1 \leq i \leq \bigl\lceil \frac{n}{2} \bigr\rceil,\; i \in \mathbb{N}$

Can somebody help me find some sort of a closed form expression for the $i$ that minimizes $L(i, n)$ given a particular $n$?